# How to build a sub-module in IntelliJ's TeamCity via Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, teamcity

I have a parent project which contains several sub modules created with **Maven**.

I need to run the sub modules one by one and then last one is report generator module in team city using Maven. How to do this?

The main project is **aggregrator project** contains sub modules which are **automation testing** and **report generator project**.

Report Generator project has no artifact dependency but it's has a dependency on the output report file generated from other submodules. The report module will grab the HTML report file from relative directory prior running the sub modules. Once the HTML report file is grabbed, it creates a `.zip` file that contains several reports which is sent out in a single shot.

I want to build a sub-module created with Maven in IntelliJ's TeamCity. How can we achieve that?

Comment: when you say navigate? what do you mean by that? Do you want to compile?

Comment: I want to run the tests for submodule?

Comment: You want to run tests and generate report for all those modules form parent right?

Comment: No need, I just want to run the tests for each submodules, There are report generator sub module

Comment: report generator module in same parent too?

Comment: Report generator isin same parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255376/discussion-between-anish-b-and-nicholas).

Comment: can you post your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to run the submodule in the IntellJ's teamcity with Maven:**

1. I assume there is a parent Maven project created/import already in the team city. For example: I imported a project with the name 'aggregator'.

[image]

2. Now I will create a submodule via teamcity. Click to **Administration** option on the top right hand corner beside the profile logo.

[image]

3. Click on **Projects** option on the left side and then click on the parent name to open the Project tab.

[image]

4. Scroll down at the end, you will find a subprojects tab. There will be + button to create new sub module within the parent project.

[image]

5. After clicking on + button, it will land you to the page where it will ask sub-module to create via repository url or manually.

I will be doing it manually for now. I give the name of the sub module as 'report-generator'.

[image]

6. Click on the create button. It will create the sub-module successfully with the message.

> Project "Aggregator / report-generator" has been successfully created.
> You can now create a build configuration.

[image]

7. Now, you have to create build configuration. On the sub-module project page, you will find the tab there. Go there and click on the plus button.

[image]

8. Enter any name for the build configuration and click on the create.

[image]

9. Click on Attach existing VCS Root and select the parent module's one. Or you can create a new VCS root by clicking on Create new VCS Root.

Now, as soon as you select this, the teamcity will auto-detect the presence of the build tools and setting that you are using for parent project and recommend it if you want to use it for sub-module also.

In your case, you want to run the sub-module with maven. So, in that case, select **Maven** as build step.

[image]

10. Click on **Use selected** and you are done.

[image]

11. Click on Run to execute sub-module build and it will use Maven as build step from parent.

[image]

Successful Execution of the sub-module via Maven build step.

[image]

Comment: How to point the repo to sub modues when created sub project?

Comment: @nicholas I didn't understand the requirement.

Comment: @nicholas See point 9 where you can select the VCS root, you can select the parent VCS root for the sub-project. I guess that's what you are asking for. Correct me if I understood wrongly. The newly sub-project will point to parent by that way.